# Translate mySQL WHERE statement into hibernate restriction

Tags: mysql, hibernate, java-8, where-clause, predicate

How to translate mySQL WHERE restriction into hibernate Expression restriction or Predicate restriction? 
MySQL statement is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Zaposleni 
WHERE ime= 'Marko' 
OR adresa= 'Uzice' 
AND brojgodina BETWEEN 25 AND 50 
OR visinadohotka BETWEEN 10 AND 30
```

Comment: Please show you WHERE conditions

Comment: How would you answer the following question: "How to translate Spanish verbs into English verbs?" Yeah, you couldn't without asking back or saying "look into the dictionary". So edit your question to have a proper problem statement.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Zaposleni WHERE ime= 'Marko'  OR adresa= 'Uzice'  AND brojgodina BETWEEN 25 AND 50 OR visinadohotka BETWEEN 10 AND 30

Comment: use hibernate Disjunction for OR clause

Answer (score 0):

Use Disjunction for OR Clause

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(YourEntityClassName.class);

Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
Criterion ime = Restrictions.eq("ime","Marko");
Criterion adresa = Restrictions.eq("adresa","Uzice");
disjunction.add(ime);
disjunction.add(adresa);

Disjunction disjunctionForBetweenCondition = Restrictions.disjunction();
Criterion brojgodina = Restrictions.between("brojgodina", 25, 50);
Criterion visinadohotka = Restrictions.between("visinadohotka", 10, 30);
disjunctionForBetweenCondition.add(brojgodina);
disjunctionForBetweenCondition.add(visinadohotka);

criteria.add(disjunction);
criteria.add(disjunctionForBetweenCondition);
```